# button clicked at index in UIAlertViewDelegate not getting called

Tags: swift

Earlier in Objective-C we were using delegate:self in `UIAlertView` so that we were able to call methods like buttonclicked at index....but now  in swift where do I set that delegate? because my buttonclicked at index method is not getting called..

```
import UIKit

class ViewController:UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UIAlertViewDelegate{

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!{
let cell :UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: nil)
cell.text = "HI \(indexPath.row)"
cell.detailTextLabel.text = "SWIFT"
return cell
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
 return 5
}

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!)
 {


   var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Demo", message: "You have selected row number\(indexPath.row)", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "KILL", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive, handler: nil))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "PUNE", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Mumbai", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Kolkata", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Chennai", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


 }
func demoFunction (myName:NSString)
{
    NSLog("%@", "swapnil")
}

func alertView(alertView: UIAlertView!, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int)
{
    NSLog("%@", "YOU PRESSED OK" )
    switch (buttonIndex)
        {
        case 0:NSLog("%@", "YOU PRESSED OK" )
        case 1:NSLog("%@", "YOU PRESSED KILLER" )
        case 2:NSLog("%@", "YOU PRESSED PUNE" )
        case 3:NSLog("%@", "YOU PRESSED MUMBAI" )
        case 4:NSLog("%@", "YOU PRESSED KOLKATA" )
        case 5:NSLog("%@", "YOU PRESSED Chennai" )
        default :NSLog("%@", "You have pressed default")

        }

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIAlertController` does not implement a delegate property. It uses the handler parameter of `-addAction:` to handle a tap on a button. Here is an example of how this is done:

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "RandomTitle", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:{(alert :UIAlertAction!) -> void in
    //Handle action here. 
    //You can also use the alert title property to differentiate between 
    //UIAlertActions and hand the same closure in to each one. E.i.

    if(action.title == "first option"){
        //handle when the user taps the "first option" button.
    }
}))
```

Comment: Can you please explain (alert :UIAlertAction!) why we are using ! operation here at the end

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use delegate method, in fact `UIAlertController` doesn't provide delegation.

In your case, your Alert Action should be like this:

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:    {(alert :UIAlertAction!) in
        println("YOU PRESSED OK")

        }))
```

and so on for every action!